# inyectar sesión Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

estoy utilizando Spring Security para la seguridad de mi apliación web.
Necesito guardar varios o todos los atributos del usuario que se loguea pero Spring security solo guarda el username. Quisiera saber cómo agregar más datos a la sesión.

He encontrado que lo puedo hacer inyectando el objeto en HttpSession, pero no encuestro mucha (casi nada de) información sobre cómo hacerlo.

**UPDATE**

```
@Service
public class CustomerUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    public List authorities(Agente agente){
        List lista = new ArrayList();
        lista.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADM"));
        return lista;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Agente agente = new AgenteDao().obtenerAgente(username);
        if(agente == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario No encontrado");
        }

        return new User(agente.getId_agente(), agente.getPassword_agente(), true, true, true, true, authorities(agente));
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerUserDetailsService customerUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customerUserDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void ConfigureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customerUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
        @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM') or hasRole('ROLE_VENDEDOR')") 
        .antMatchers("/usuarios").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM')")
        .antMatchers("/ventas").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM') or hasRole('ROLE_VENDEDOR')")
        .antMatchers("/reportes").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que falta un poco de información por añadir en tu pregunta, me arriesgo a responderla con lo que estas solicitando. El único problema es que no te puedo indicar exáctamente donde y como deberías implementar dicha solución, ni puedo probar el código en este momento. Te invito a completar tu pregunta añadiendo el controlador que estes usando para iniciar la autenticación.

Lo que estás buscando existe, y se llaman Scope Session Bean. Son beans que pueden ser injectados en el controlador y tienen un ámbito de la sesión al igual que sería HttpSession.

Como requisito, hay que tener en cuenta que solo está disponible para aplicaciones web de Spring.

Para injectar dichos componentes solo hay que definirlos de la siguiente manera:

```js
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class InformacionUsuario {
    // ...
}
```

Para luego injectarlo en el controlador:

```js
@Controller
public class ControladorPropio {
    @Inject
    private InformacionUsuario informacionUsuario;
```

A modo de referencia te dejo unos enlaces, para que puedas aprender más en detalle sobre este tema.

1- [Documentacion Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/html/sm-scopes.html)

2- [Documentación Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)

3- [Ejemplo MkYong](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/)

Vuelvo a pedirte que añadas tu controlador en la pregunta, para poder responderte sobre tu propio código. Así cuando otra persona busque esta información, lo vea claro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pudieras hacer, como primer paso, es crear un Wrapper del usuario que deseas, de tipo UserDetails, algo como:

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User {

    private final Agente agente;

    public CustomUserDetails(Agente agente, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(agente.getId_agente(), agente.getPassword_agente(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
        this.agente = agente;
    }

    public Agente getAgente(){
        return this.agente;
    }

}
```

Para poderlo colocar, tendrías que modificar tu servicio de esta forma:

```
@Service
public class CustomerUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    public List authorities(Agente agente){
        List lista = new ArrayList();
        lista.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADM"));
        return lista;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Agente agente = new AgenteDao().obtenerAgente(username);
        if(agente == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario No encontrado");
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(agente, authorities(agente));
    }

}
```

Con esto automáticamente Spring Security colocará en el Principal el UserDetails que le envies, y lo podrías recuperar en MVC de la siguiente forma:

```
@RequestMapping("/me")
@ResponseBody
public Agente me(Principal principal){
    return ((CustomUserDetails)principal).getAgente();
}
```

Así no tendrías que colocar en sesión al usuario, directamente.

Comment: He hecho los cambios tal cual indicaste, pero cuando quiero obtener el agente me sale el siguiente error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to CustomUserDetails**